# jquery.confirm in .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a nice library named [jquery.confirm](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm) and I have problem when I want to use its .confirm() method in the jQuery .click() function.

Here is my code:

```
$('#car-url').click(function()
{
    var empty = true;
    $(".departurePlace input, .arrivalPlace input, .cost input").each(function()
    {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() != '' || input.val() != 0)
            empty = false;
    });
    if (empty == false)
        $(".confirm").confirm();
});
```

As you can see I just want to check the inputs before eventually show the dialog box.

I first [contacted the developer](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm/issues/34) because I thought that was a bug, but according to him it is not.

Any ideas?

Edit: It can not be my selectors because when I try this:

```
$('#car-url').click(function()
{
    var empty;
    $(".departurePlace input, .arrivalPlace input, .cost input").each(function(){
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() != '' || input.val() != 0)
    {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

I have the alert box as desired when one input is not empty.

Comment: As the developer commented in the issue, adding the `empty` declaration outside the closure scope makes it visible in the final if, so this should work...are you still having the issue with this code?

Comment: Yep, adding the empty declaration changes nothing.

Comment: Is the code inside the `each` executed? The query with the spaces doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: It's for the example, the real code looks like this: '#requestDate input, ...'

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Tip: You could use just `!input.val()` for testing. Or even better, just `!$(this).val()`.

Comment: Are you trying to say that after checking the first element the confirm appears right away?

Comment: @MikeAnte Nope, nothing appears even if one of the inputs is not empty. I will try to post a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue has anything to do with the confirm plugin. As [Raibaz suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386593/jquery-confirm-in-click-function/25395345#comment39592709_25386593), it's your selectors.

Change your ids from `my input1` to `my-input1`.

A couple fiddles to illustrate:

[Fiddle: selectors with spaces](http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/dLsfzax1/1/) (based on your original code)

[Fiddle: selectors without spaces](http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/dLsfzax1/)

```
$('#my-url').click(function() {
    var empty = true;

    $("#my-input1, #my-input2").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            empty = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (! empty) {
        confirm('confirmed');
    }
});
```